# replace values in pandas column when N number of NaNs exist in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the foll. pandas dataframe:

```
2018-05-25  0.000381  0.264318     land    2018-05-25
2018-05-26  0.000000  0.264447     land    2018-05-26
2018-05-27  0.000000  0.264791     NaN           NaT
2018-05-28  0.000000  0.265253     NaN           NaT
2018-05-29  0.000000  0.265720     NaN           NaT
2018-05-30  0.000000  0.266066     land    2018-05-30
2018-05-31  0.000000  0.266150     NaN           NaT
2018-06-01  0.000000  0.265816     NaN           NaT
2018-06-02  0.000000  0.264892     land    2018-06-02
2018-06-03  0.000000  0.263191     NaN           NaT
2018-06-04  0.000000  0.260508     land    2018-06-04
2018-06-05  0.000000  0.256619     NaN           NaT
2018-06-06  0.000000  0.251286     NaN           NaT
2018-06-07  0.000000  0.244250     NaN           NaT
2018-06-08  0.000000  0.235231     NaN           NaT
2018-06-09  0.000000  0.223932     land    2018-06-09
```

I want to replace values in the 3rd column with NaN when there are 3 or more consecutive NaN values in the 4th column. The output should look like this:

```
2018-05-25  0.000381  0.264318     land    2018-05-25
2018-05-26  0.000000  0.264447     land    2018-05-26
2018-05-27  0.000000  0.264791     NaN           NaT
2018-05-28  0.000000  0.265253     NaN           NaT
2018-05-29  0.000000  NaN          NaN           NaT
2018-05-30  0.000000  0.266066     land    2018-05-30
2018-05-31  0.000000  0.266150     NaN           NaT
2018-06-01  0.000000  0.265816     NaN           NaT
2018-06-02  0.000000  0.264892     land    2018-06-02
2018-06-03  0.000000  0.263191     NaN           NaT
2018-06-04  0.000000  0.260508     land    2018-06-04
2018-06-05  0.000000  0.256619     NaN           NaT
2018-06-06  0.000000  0.251286     NaN           NaT
2018-06-07  0.000000  NaN          NaN           NaT
2018-06-08  0.000000  NaN          NaN           NaT
2018-06-09  0.000000  0.223932     land    2018-06-09
```

I am also ok if instead of replacing by NaNs, the row is completely removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**, more versatile approach for any threshold of consecutive `NaN`'s:

```
threshold = 3
mask = df.d.notna()
df.loc[(~mask).groupby(mask.cumsum()).transform('cumsum') >= threshold, 'c'] = np.nan
```

You can simply check if the row, as well as shifting the row twice are all null (I named your columns `a-e`:

```
df.loc[df.d.isnull() & df.d.shift().isnull() & df.d.shift(2).isnull(), 'c'] = np.nan

# Result:

             a         b         c     d           e
0   2018-05-25  0.000381  0.264318  land  2018-05-25
1   2018-05-26  0.000000  0.264447  land  2018-05-26
2   2018-05-27  0.000000  0.264791   NaN         NaT
3   2018-05-28  0.000000  0.265253   NaN         NaT
4   2018-05-29  0.000000       NaN   NaN         NaT
5   2018-05-30  0.000000  0.266066  land  2018-05-30
6   2018-05-31  0.000000  0.266150   NaN         NaT
7   2018-06-01  0.000000  0.265816   NaN         NaT
8   2018-06-02  0.000000  0.264892  land  2018-06-02
9   2018-06-03  0.000000  0.263191   NaN         NaT
10  2018-06-04  0.000000  0.260508  land  2018-06-04
11  2018-06-05  0.000000  0.256619   NaN         NaT
12  2018-06-06  0.000000  0.251286   NaN         NaT
13  2018-06-07  0.000000       NaN   NaN         NaT
14  2018-06-08  0.000000       NaN   NaN         NaT
15  2018-06-09  0.000000  0.223932  land  2018-06-09
```

Comment: thanks @user3483202, can you soln scale if instead of 3 or more consecutive NaNs, I wanted to check for 15 or more consecutive NaNs ?

Comment: If you are searching for a large number of consecutive nulls, there is an approach which is slightly longer but much more elegant than shifting over and over.  I will update my answer soon.

Comment: @Dark whoops, forgot I used a temp variable :P

Comment: thanks! what does `(~mask).groupby(mask.cumsum()).transform('cumsum')` do?

Comment: It creates a series where each value is the current number of consecutive `NaN`s, so by checking for that series >= threshold, you replace any values where the current number of consecutive `NaN`s is above the desired threshold.  If you just check the output for that snippet it's a bit more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach where the consecutive appearance of null is n i.e

```
n = 3
# create a mask
x = df[3].isnull()
# counter to restart the count of nan once there is a no nan consecutively 
se = (x.cumsum() - x.cumsum().where(~x).fillna(method='pad').fillna(0))


df.loc[se>=n,2] = np.nan

       0         1         2     3           4
0   2018-05-25  0.000381  0.264318  land  2018-05-25
1   2018-05-26  0.000000  0.264447  land  2018-05-26
2   2018-05-27  0.000000  0.264791   NaN         NaT
3   2018-05-28  0.000000  0.265253   NaN         NaT
4   2018-05-29  0.000000       NaN   NaN         NaT
5   2018-05-30  0.000000  0.266066  land  2018-05-30
6   2018-05-31  0.000000  0.266150   NaN         NaT
7   2018-06-01  0.000000  0.265816   NaN         NaT
8   2018-06-02  0.000000  0.264892  land  2018-06-02
9   2018-06-03  0.000000  0.263191   NaN         NaT
10  2018-06-04  0.000000  0.260508  land  2018-06-04
11  2018-06-05  0.000000  0.256619   NaN         NaT
12  2018-06-06  0.000000  0.251286   NaN         NaT
13  2018-06-07  0.000000       NaN   NaN         NaT
14  2018-06-08  0.000000       NaN   NaN         NaT
15  2018-06-09  0.000000  0.223932  land  2018-06-09
```

Comment: Kept trying to get something like this to work, was missing the `pad`, nice answer!